# Spring-boot BASIC Authentication not working in IE browser

Tags: spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have done basic authentication using springboot with BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint and custom filter. It working as expected in Chrome but not working in IE browser.

First its prompting login page if entered wrong credentials then if we reload the page and its trying to authenticate with previous details only and not prompting login page again in IE browser but this same was working in chrome as expected.

Code as below:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());

        http.addFilterAt(getCustomAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint code:

```
public class MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        response.getOutputStream().println(authException.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        setRealmName("localhost");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

CustomFilter Code:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  @Autowired
  AuthUsersService authUsersService;

  @Autowired
  public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

    super(authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Authentication authResult) throws IOException {

       System.out.println("Successful");

    return;

  }


  @Override
  protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("UN-Successful");

    return;

  }  

}
```

Can anyone please suggest on this why above code not working on IE browser ?

Comment: Why the custom entrypoint and filter? It doesn't add anything (in fact it breaks things, due to not calling `super.onUnsuccessfulAuthentication` and `super.onSuccessfulAuthentication`. Looks like you are overriding the wrong things to only plugin a custom way of retrieving users.

Comment: custom entrypoint is used to show login error in case tried with wrong credentials and custom filter is used to log user as i have not added log user code in above post as this lengthy code so. but the above code is working in chrome as expected but not working in IE. thanks @M. Deinum

Comment: You generally shouldn't be exposting the error message from a security perspective (it gives valuable information to a hacker! existing/non-existing user etc). Also if you want logging you are better of writing an `ApplicationListener` that logs `AuthenticationEvents` (Spring Boot actually does this out-of-the-box already!). Try with the default basic authentication entrypoint and filter. Might be that writing a message breaks things in IE.

Comment: Can you provide one example on this please? @M. Deinum

Comment: Sample of what exactly?

Comment: exactly implementing the same as above functionality. @  M. Deinum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200219/discussion-between-krishna-and-m-deinum).

Comment: I don't know what the above functionality is because you didn't include it. For logging you can implement your own `AuditEventRepository ` and implement the `add` method (and throw excetion in the find if you only want logging). That does require a dependency on the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` if you don't want/need that just implement an `ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>` that way you get all the information needed (success/failure/who/when/what). You can also implement `ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthorizationEven>` if you want to log authorization events as well.